# Float not working

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tournament</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="tournament">
            <div class="round-1">
                <div class="game">
                    <div class="contender-1">
                        P1
                    </div>
                    <div class="contender-2">
                        P2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="game">
                    <div class="contender-1">
                        P3
                    </div>
                    <div class="contender-2">
                        P4
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.contender-1,
.contender-2 {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
width: 120px;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding-left: 2px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
 }

 .contender-1 {
border-bottom: 0px;
}

 .game {
margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.line {
float: left;
background-color: red;
height: 10px;
width: 210px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

The line class is placed under the game div, and not right next to it.

I have no idea what's causing this. Is it the bootstrap css causing the issues? I have not touched it. Disregard all the other divs and whatnot, only game and line, I guess.

Or is there a better solution for creating lines going out of the box? I'm creating a tournament page so I need lines connecting the brackets. I hope you understand my post. I need lines on both sides of the two boxes.

EDIT: TUrning off the bootstrap css doesn't change anything. What's happening here?

Sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J39z.png

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of what you're trying to do?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lya2htS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would place your content in the bootstrap grid. For example if you want a two columns grid. You  can see here how they do it: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

If you do not want to use this grid and want to achieve the effect you are after. You need to float the game container also to left. Otherwise the game container will take the full width of its parent container or body, and push the line container down.

```
.game {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  float: left;
}
```

See here the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sc8EJ/5/

Comment: That solution works perfectly if I add a clear: both in the .game div. Will this cause any problems though?

Comment: Maybe there's an easier solution creating this though? http://i.imgur.com/HHCHLLT.png

Comment: Also if I use the grid, the line will not stick to the box so to speak, becuase of the padding every grid has.

Comment: If you add clear: both to the game container it will make the first game container not to be floating left next to the second game container. And yes, the grid is no option here. It all depends what visual effect/layout you want to achieve.

Comment: What if I want to have lines before (left) of the boxes? Or on both sides even. Then the clear:both solution doesn't really work since I can't float the game div since it cleared.